# How to start with SuperUser?

Tags: support, badges, site-crossover

What is the connection between SU and other Q&A sites from the group? If  got 1 badge will I have it also on 3 other Q&A sites?

Answer (score 4):

> If got 1 badge will I have it also on
>   3 other Q&A sites?

nope, you will have to earn your merits separately on each site :)

you will, however, receive a little bonus (100 reputation points IIRC) if you associate your account with any of the other web sites, so you can vote and leave comments right away.

Comment: man - you are fast heh thnx :)

Comment: WTF, why a downvote on this? +1

Comment: IIRC you need to have a minimum rep on one of your accounts before you will get the 100 bonus points when associating accounts

Comment: What's the minimum rep? Sorry if it's listed somewhere obvious and I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Molly go associate your accounts :-P